# Django view function to create a post to the database

Tags: django, foreign-keys

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Paper(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    abstract = models.TextField(null=False)
    keywords = models.TextField(null=False)

class Rate(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User)
    paper_id = models.ForeignKey(Paper)
    isLike = models.BooleanField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I have the following models in Django. And I am unsure how to write a function in views that create a Rate when the Button URL is triggered. isLike should be set as True if the user rated the paper or False if they did not. Thanks you For your assistance.

Comment: To increase your how sure you are, how about you read the Django docs first? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/

Comment: You really should complete [this great tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/). It will answer most questions like this one.